# Is it safe to manipulate df.values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is it safe to manipulate the `values` attribute of a pandas DataFrame? For example, I'm using

```
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, x)
```

and it works from what I can tell, but I'd like to make sure it cannot break randomly.

Concretely:
is `for i in range(n): df.values[i,i] = x[i]` guaranteed to always have the same effect as `for i in range(n): df.iloc[i, i] = x[i]`?

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([2,2]))
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, np.ones(2))
df
```

displays a DataFrame with values `[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]]` as expected, but I want to be sure this does not rely on non-guaranteed behavior that may change depending on the pandas version or the dataframe size.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input and expected output for better understanding?

Comment: It does not look like it'll break. Maybe you can explain your use-case better and we can try and find a better solution.

Comment: I do this a lot.  The main danger is that when you drop down to numpy, you lose index alignment, which can cause issues if you aren't careful or are operating on other objects that expect a labeled dataset.  For a simple dataframe you should have no issues.

Comment: @user3483203 Concretely then: is `for i in range(n): df.values[i,i] = x[i]` guaranteed to have the same effect as `for i in range(n): df.iloc[i, i] = x[i]`

Comment: It seems to me it should work fine, although a bit unusual. I would just make sure the indices for rows and columns are retained (in other words, that the result is still a dataframe with the same metadata). Apparently you don't need to worry about index alignment since you are only working with that same df.

Comment: @MayankPorwal For example, `df` could be an empirical covariance matrix, and `x` are variances for individual variables that I know exactly for some reason

Comment: For a simple dataframe it works, but with a mix of column dtypes I wouldn't count on it.  The relation between the data as stored in the frame and the `values` property is complex.  Read the `values` docs and the related `to_numpy` method.